# How to use where like for a string that includes double quotes

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

In my Firebird (version 2.5) table there is a JSON string. I need to search to find if an entire value is equal to some value, so I want to include the double quotes in the where query.

For example:

```sql
SELECT myfield FROM mytable WHERE json like '"%thisIsSomeString%"'
```

Example JSON to match:

```json
{"id1":"fake1", "id2":"thisIsSomeString"}
```

Example JSON to *not* match:

```json
{"id1":"fake1", "id2":"thisIsSomeString but with extra data"}
```

It doesn't work, I guess it is a matter of escaping the string.
I checked the JSON value using FlameRobin, it seems like a normal JSON string.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide a [mre], including sample data so we know what you're trying to match, because at first glance, it sounds like you want to search `'%"somevalue"%'` instead of `'"%somevalue%"'`.

Comment: I updated the question. I want to match the `thisIsSomeString`, but only if it is surrounded by double quotes in the string that is stored in the table. i.e, I want to match the exact string `"thisIsSomeString"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for the string `"thisIsSomeString"`, then you need to use `LIKE '%"thisIsSomeString"%'`.

The predicate `like '"%thisIsSomeString%"'` you tried looks for a value that starts with a `"`, then has zero or more characters, then the string `thisIsSomeString`, then zero or more characters and then ends with `"`. This doesn't match your JSON values, because those start with `{` and end with `}`, nor does it match your requirement to find the substring `"thisIsSomeString"`.

Answer (score 1):

Why using complex tools to confuse yourself and the server when there are easy tools? You make mistake in the `LIKE` - but you just did not have to use it.

You wanted to check if the database value contains some substring - the SQL has exactly that check for you.

```
SELECT myfield FROM mytable 
WHERE json CONTAINING '"thisIsSomeString"'`
```

Comment: Containing is - contrary to like - case-insensitive.

Comment: I actually didn't know that there is a keyword for `containing`. Nice to know! In my case it should have been good enough because I was looking for numbers.